# Allocating mutiple pages and create continuous address space

Tags: kernel, allocation, continuous

I want to create a big buffer in kernel with continuous address space using `struct page`.

The idea is to use `alloc_page` to create `nr_pages` * pages (I must strongly NOT use `alloc_pages(...,order)` which returns one `struct page *page`) and then somehow combine these `nr_pages * PAGE_SIZE` space.

If I `alloc_page` I can then `addr = page_address(page)` so that I can memcpy to/from this 4k space. But what about more space?

Any ideas will be helpful

Comment: How much is your big buffer ?

Comment: Something bigger than one page (thus PAGE SIZE). Like 64k, or 16 pages

Comment: You can just use kmalloc,  on a 64 bit kernel you can allocate up to 4 MB buffer

Comment: I strongly need to use mutiple pages, because this is a part of an API.
Or maybe I can `addr =kmalloc` but I must somehow get the `struct page *pages` of this memory.

Comment: You have the order parameter which enables you to specify the size of the continuous pages, 9 means 2mb space of continuous pages